# Making bufferedreader from loop, to next line?

Tags: java, string, loops, bufferedreader, joptionpane

sorry about the poor title, didn't quite know what to call it! 
 basically I made the loop below to show the first six lines from the file, got that sorted. When it comes to showing the six lines though, I'm not sure how to get them to appear on a different line each time. The closest I got, was including the joptionpane in the loop, showing one line, then on the next joptionpane on the next et al. The second joptionpane at the bottom shows all the lines but on the same line instead of the next etc. How ought I make it so they appear on the next line each time? \n doesn't seem to work.

```
private static void doOptionTwo(int balance) throws IOException {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option two selected ");
    String sum = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
    String line1 = br.readLine();
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line1);
            sum = sum + line1;

    }

    if (br != null)br.close();
    String log = sum;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, log);

}
```

Comment: You use the same escape char as in a normal String for a break:
\n

Answer (score 3):

Use StringBuilder instead of String which is initialized as null. You could do whatever you want with following code:

```
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 String newLineCharacter = System.getProperty("line.separator");
 for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
     stringBuilder.append(br.readLine());
     stringBuilder.append(newLineCharacter);//note: will add new line at end as well..
}
```

Comment: Even better since Java 8 we can use `StringJoiner` with `System.getProperty("line.separator")` as delimiter (or `System.lineSeparator()` which is little shorter code than `System.getProperty("line.separator")`).

Answer (score 1):

Just insert break each time in your String :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    String line1 = br.readLine(); 
    sum += line1 + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `"\n"` between the lines.

```
String sum = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
    String line1 = br.readLine();
    sum += line1 + "\n";
}
```

Or more appropriately, use a `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
    String line1 = br.readLine();
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append('\n');
    }
    sb.append(line1);
}
String sum = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more efficient :

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Option two selected ");
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
    String line1 = br.readLine();
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line1);
             build.append(sum).append("\n");
    }

    if (br != null)br.close();
    System.out.println(build.toString());
```

Comment: With `build.append(sum+"\n");` you are kind of killing purpose of using `StringBuilder`. Use `build.append(sum).append("\n");` instead.

Comment: No it is not killing, The reason why you can use something like apend().apend().apend() chain its because it returns the Same Class as Initialize. The pointer "this" is return to the Methods by default.

Comment: I meant that `build.append(sum+"\n")` will be compiled to something like `build.append(new StringBuilder(sum).append("\n").toString())`, so in each iteration you are creating new StringBuilder instead of using already existing one (which will be returned by `append` as you already seem to know).

Comment: Actually Its not , I actually see the Real Code of StringBuilder using Decompiler hack. StringBuilder is the solution for Immutable problems.

Comment: Standard "decompiler" (`javap -c ClassName`) shows that `sum+"\n";` (assuming that `sum` is not compile-time-constant like in this case) is compiled into `StringBuilder(sum).append("\n").toString()`. Use your Decompiler to check exactly what this code will be compiled into `build.append(sum+"\n")`.

Comment: Ok I get what exactly your point.. Thats why this comes to a show System.getProperty("line.separator");